# Lasso fitting by coordinate descent: open-source implementations?

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization

What open-source implementations -- in any language -- exist out there that can compute lasso regularisation paths for linear regression by coordinate descent?

So far I am aware of:

- [glmnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html)
- [scikits.learn](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/)

Anything else out there?

Answer (score 5):

I have a MATLAB and C/C++ implementation [here](http://www.emakalic.org/blog/?page_id=7).

Let me know if you find it useful.

Comment: I only have an implementation of the Bayesian LASSO for linear regression and the LASSO for logistic regression currently uploaded. Appologies.

Comment: Your code sounds promising. Under what license are you making it available? A [BSD license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php) would allow the widest possible uses.

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look at [lasso4j](http://code.google.com/p/lasso4j/) which is an open source Java implementation of Lasso for linear regression. It is a port of the glmnet package to pure Java.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [GPL implementation of L1-regularized logistic regression](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/l1_logreg/) but via the interior-point method rather than coordinate descent.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the R package lassoshooting. It is written in C and the code is split in to two files where one of them is for the R interface and the other is more standalone (ccd_common.c).

See https://github.com/tabenius/lassoshooting